# I keep getting error ORA-01422, ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, function

I keep getting error ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. ORA-06512: at "CM420A07.ZIP_CODE_SALES_WINNER", line 6. I cannot figure out exactly what is going wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ZIP_CODE_SALES_WINNER
  RETURN VARCHAR
IS
  zipWinner VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  SELECT C.zip_code INTO zipWinner
  FROM SALE S JOIN CUSTOMER C
  ON S.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
  GROUP BY C.zip_code
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
  FROM SALE S JOIN CUSTOMER C
  ON S.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
  GROUP BY C.zip_code);  
  RETURN zipWinner;
END;
/
SELECT ZIP_CODE_SALES_WINNER FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: your error code sounds like you are using oracle, but you have tagged the question with `mysql`

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01422.php

Comment: The web site you linked says to create a cursor to handle this.

Comment: I tried to create a cursor but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: So you need more than one row if many `zip code` has same `count`?

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns more than one value.

If you do not care which zipcode will be selected if there is more than one just add rownum=1 to the query to get exactly one row:

```
SELECT zip_code INTO zipWinner FROM (
SELECT C.zip_code 
  FROM SALE S JOIN CUSTOMER C
  ON S.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
  GROUP BY C.zip_code
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
  FROM SALE S JOIN CUSTOMER C
  ON S.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
  GROUP BY C.zip_code))
  WHERE  rownum =1;
```

Comment: I understand that I guess I am confused on how to make it return only one value

Comment: What do you do in case you have two (or more) zip codes having the same count(*) ?? If you do not care just add rownum =1 to the query.

Comment: @RandyGilman rownum = 1 is a bad practice. If you think you should use it, don't because it means your query is missing something and/or fundamentally flawed. rethink and rewrite.